# How do I sort with sort_values() by 2 multiindex columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to sort a DataFrame with `MultiIndex` columns by 2 columns.
Can't reach the second column.

Tried passing it as a list of lists but got an error.
Tried passing it as a tuple also got an error

```
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by=([('Measurements','Name')], [('Measurements', 'DateCreated')]), ascending=True, inplace= False)
```

expected result: data frame sorted by `name` then by `date`.
Getting key error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by=[('Measurements','Name'), 
                               ('Measurements', 'DateCreated')], 
                           ascending=True, 
                           inplace= False)
```

Comment: Not giving an error but it is not sorting the dates

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) feature.

```
sorted_df = df.groupby(['Name', 'DateCreated'])
```

Comment: can't use groupby(), I have duplicate columns names.

Comment: Can you rename the columns?

Comment: unfortunately, no